# React Native app rejected due to "No content"

Tags: ios, react-native, app-store-connect, testflight, appstore-approval

I have an app which uses a login screen to login the users. I have just submited the app for review at Apple and recieved the following rejection message.

"During our review, we found that your app displays no content when reviewed on iPhone and iPad running iOS 14.6 on WiFI. While we cannot provide technical assistance with the reported issues, we have put together the following resources which discuss common issues seen in apps during review.
Review device details:

- Device type: iPhone and iPad
- OS version: iOS 14.6

Next Steps

Please run your app on a device to reproduce the issues, then revise and submit your app for review. If at first you're unable to reproduce the issue, try the following:

- For new apps, uninstall all previous versions of your app from a device, then install and follow the steps to reproduce.
- For app updates, install the new version as an update to the previous version, then follow the steps to reproduce.

If we misunderstood the intended behavior of your app, please reply to this message in Resolution Center to provide information on how these features were intended to work."

I have followed everything they said. I tested on both a physical device and simulator. I use wifi, i have the same iOS version and tested it on both iPad and iPhone. I do not get a blank screen. I cannot seem to reproduce this. Has anyone ever faced this problem and how can I resolve this? I am using an Express app as the backend that is hosted on AWS.

I can also mention that the connection is over HTTP and not HTTPS which is said to be ok if you only add a string to the info.plist file. But maybe its related to that?

My Info.plist on iOS:
[image]

Comment: Did you try to test it with a simulator instead of a real device? Did you check logs on your backend?

Comment: Hello and thank you for taking the time to answer! Yes, I tested on both, and no white screen appeared. Since I do not know when the reviewers are testing the app, i can not see the logs live. It is just a basic login system where i post username and password and the backend should return the user data and navigate the user the the homepage. But on the reviewers side , it does not work.

Comment: as i know they use vpn when test apps, can this cause ? , also check arbitrary loads

Comment: Did you catch any type of error showing relative alert for the user? Maybe there is an unmanaged error that is causing the blank screen.

Comment: No I do not have any errors logged or saved. Is there a way to collect this information during beta review? Im pretty new to backend and server development so I not really sure on how to save and analyse errors and crashes :( Does someone have a tip on how I can troubleshoot my login endpoint? As I said, its an express app with many different endpoints.

Comment: @CristeaVictor Thank you for taking your time! I did not know they were using a VPN. What is arbitrary loads and how can I check them?

Comment: @ShaonAhmed  <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>

Comment: I think I have already added that :( I've checked the React Native documentation regarding HTTP request and it stated that you had to add that before release if you are using HTTP.

Comment: I have added my info.plist above if someone want to look.